# Redirecting to the perticular section when click on the textbox?

Tags: html, css

I have created few forms and one pdf preview for this, whenever anyone will going to fill that form pdf preview will get updated with respect to it and after filling all the forms we can take pdf of it.

I want to be shown the particular section is getting updating (like changing the background color or underline it) on right side 
when you giving the input on particular text box.

Please find the live code at http://ibus.proserindustries.com/

Comment: please explain your problem, it's unclear to me.

Comment: Please include the code that you're using.

Comment: @Adarsha Jha                                                                                         
=> Please once again visit to http://ibus.proserindustries.com/ and go to property tab and go to the section Appliances/Furniture and add something in tubelight textbox you will see from right size pdf view it will redirecting to that tube light row of the table but am unable to insert more that one character in that textbox, how we will achieve it so that it will get redirect and also want to enter as many words as much required.

Comment: @Faisal Rashid         =>                           
                 $('#propertytubelight').keyup(function() {
                $('#propertytubelight1').text($('#propertytubelight').val());
                window.location = '#propertytubelight1';

            });         (Consider "propertytubelight" is the id of the textbox and "propertytubelight1" is the id of the div where this text get updated

Comment: Since, you're not adding any JavaScript here, I would suggest that you add an attribute such as data-target to each of your inputs and using javascript each time input event occurs on that input field, scroll your preview pane into position by giving the respective area there the same id as specified in the data-target.

Comment: Try this

 $('#propertytubelight').keyup(function() { $('#propertytubelight1').text($('#propertytubelight').val()); window.location = '#propertytubelight1'; $('#propertytubelight').focus()});

Comment: @ Faisal Rashid => Please explain with example , am not getting it want you telling

Comment: @ Faisal Rashid => thanks, let me check it..

Comment: @RahulJadhav
Have updated it.
 $('#propertytubelight').keyup(function() { $('#propertytubelight1').text($('#propertytubelight').val()); document.querySelector('#propertytubelight1').scrollIntoView(true);});

Comment: @Faisal Rashid => i did the changes as per you given and it's working find thanks for the help, but rather than moving that section it will moving the whole page up, how can we avoid this?

Comment: @RahulJadhav My bad, your demo page didn't have this problem. Here's the updated code

$('#propertytubelight').keyup(function() { $('#propertytubelight1').text($('#propertytubelight').val()); document.querySelector('#propertytubelight1').scrollIntoView({behaviour: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start'});})

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now as i expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer from the comment.

```
$("#propertytubelight").keyup(function() {
  $("#propertytubelight1").text($("#propertytubelight").val());
    document.querySelector("#propertytubelight1").scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "start" });
});
```

This uses scrollIntoView method to scroll the input field with it's linked html element